# Time series in Driverless AI H2O

Tags: prediction, h2o, driverless-ai

I have time series data with two column: Date and Volume such as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbAET.png)

I want to predict volume of next day, so how can I setup parameters?

P/S: i set forecast horizon equal 1 but output predict show only 5 last day in time series. :(

Answer (score 1):

To predict the future dates, you can upload a dataset that has the dates of interest (specify dates in the future) and provide anything additional that may be known (group ids or features known in the future). Then run/score your predictions on this new dataset.

Here is an example dataset to upload for a model that was trained up to 2020-05-31.

```
+------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
|    Date    | Group_ID | Known_Feature_1 | Known_Feature_2 |
+------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2020-06-01 | A        |               3 |                1|
| 2020-06-02 | A        |               2 |                2|
| 2020-06-03 | A        |               4 |                1|
| 2020-06-01 | B        |               3 |                0|
| 2020-06-02 | B        |               2 |                1|
| 2020-06-03 | B        |               4 |                0|
+------------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```